# Why this java servlet doesn't work [OpenShift+Tomact6+Git+Jboss]

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, jboss, openshift

I've created Openshift application and now I'm trying to edit it.
Here is project structure:

http://my.jetscreenshot.com/demo/20130525-t2mt-28kb

I've added this code into index.html:

```
<form action="/uploadFile" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
    <input type="file" name="uploadFile" />
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

And finally I've created servlet file fileUploader.java:

```
package main.java;
import *;

@WebServlet(name = "uploadFile",urlPatterns = {"/uploadFile"})
@MultipartConfig
public class fileUploader extends javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet {

//class code
}
```

You can see @WebServlet annotation here, I read that it'is enought, but it doesn't work (404 error), so I added code in web.xml:

```
<servlet>
<servlet-name>uploadFile</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>main.java.fileUploader</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>uploadFile</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/uploadFile</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

And index.html works, but servlet doesn't. It gived 500 error now:

---

```
type Exception report
message 
description The server encountered an internal error () that prevented it from fulfilling this request.
exception 

javax.servlet.ServletException: Wrapper cannot find servlet class main.java.fileUploader or a class it depends on
org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:859)
org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:602)
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)


root cause 

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: main.java.fileUploader
org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1680)
org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1526)
org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:859)
org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:602)
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)


note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/6.0.35 logs.
```

I made a research on this problem but I still have no idea where the problem is

Comment: Do you see the file `WEB-INF/classes/main/java/fileUploader.class` in your WAR?

Comment: I don't. WEB-INF/ directory doesn't even consist classes/ folder. It may sound crazy but how could I compile fileUploader.class in WEB-INF/classes/main/java/ folder from fileUploader.java within current JBoss project?

Comment: It seems your WAR isn't getting built properly. How are you deploying it on JBoss? Using Maven or by configuring Servers in Eclipse?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using Maven to build your WAR it's perhaps packaging classes from `src/main/java` to `WEB-INF/classes` and not from the `src` folder. The difference is that Maven thinks your classes are in the default (no namespace) package i.e. without any package statement.

But your Eclipse is configured with `src` as your source directory instead of `src/main/java` and hence it has added `package main.java;` statement to your classes which now conflicts with the Maven defaults.

In your Eclipse, right click on `src` > Build Path > Remove from Build Path. Then navigate to `src\main\java` and right click > Build Path > Add as Source Directory. Let Eclipse also fix your package statements i.e. either remove `package main.java;` or create package folders like `src\main\java\main\java\fileUploader.java`. (It's NOT recommended to use camel case for Class names by the way.)

Comment: I just tried to do this, but IDE said that src\main\java is already a souce folder

Comment: Also target/classes is setted as default output folder, but it doesn't consist classes files too

Comment: (1) First remove `src` as source folder. Then add `java` as source folder. Order is important. (2) You won't see class files from JBoss. Navigate to target/classes in Explorer. By the way target/classes get copied to WEB-INF/classes (on the Server) when you do Run As from your IDE.

Answer (score 0):

> Hope you have placed your fileUploader Servlet class in
>   WEB-INF/classes/main/java directory.

Or

> You have palced the lib containing your fileUploader class in
>   WEB-INF/lib direcotyry

Comment: WEB-INF/ directory doesn't even consist classes/ folder. It may sound crazy but how could I compile fileUploader.class in WEB-INF/classes/main/java/ folder from fileUploader.java within current JBoss project?

Comment: @Roman Actually once you're done compiling the current JBoss project you usually run a build script (Ant or Maven) that makes a WAR (with required compiled classes in WEB-INF/classes folder). This could also be done by selecting Run As > Run on Server via Eclipse.

Comment: @Ravi I use JBoss IDE, so each time I do some changes I select Run As>Run on Server but nothig appears at WEB_INF

Comment: @Roman Please note that WEB-INF/classes folder wouldn't appear in your workspace i.e. inside the JBoss project folder structure. It would get deployed on your server. For example, in Tomcat at <tomcat-home>/webapps/<your-web-app-name>/WEB-INF/classes but then Tomcat should be configured correctly in your IDE.